# Given $R \in \mathbb R$, choose $a,b,c$ from discrete set so that $a^{-1} + b^{-1} + c^{-1} \approx R^{-1}$

Tags: optimization

I am working with the following equation (parallel resistors):

$\frac{1}{R_g} = \frac{1}{R_1} + \frac{1}{R_2} + \frac{1}{R_3}$

The values of $R_1, R_2$ and $ R_3$ are discrete - lets say 256 steps in increments of 3:
$$R_1,R_2,R_3 \in \{3n : 1 \leq n \leq 256\}$$

Given some $R_g \in \mathbb R$, I want to find the best of choice of $R_1, R_2$ and $R_3$ so that they come closest to the value $1/R_g$ as per the equation above. In other words, I want to minimize the following:
$$\left| \frac 1 {R_1} + \frac 1 {R_2} + \frac 1 {R_3} - \frac 1 {R_g} \right|$$
My current solution is a look up table or calculating values on the fly until the error is small enough.

This sounds not very smart and I want to believe that there is a more intelligent solution.

Is there?

Comment: Optimal in what sense and what are you trying to optimize? What error are you talking about? Try to define your question clearly and make it self contained.

Comment: I think this could be a good question if it was edited appropriately. Are you trying to ask how to obtain the closest value to $1/R_g$ given a certain set of allowed values for $R_1$, $R_2$ and $R_3$?

Comment: @ Myridium: Yes - please advise if further clarifaction is necessary

Comment: @Erik5000 Since this is math.stackexchange, I would suggest wording the question with minimal reference to the circuitry itself. i.e. *"Given that I can choose $R_1$, $R_2$ and $R_3$ from this set: $\{3n : 0 \leq n \leq 256\}$, what method can I use minimize $| 1/R_1 + 1/R_2 + 1/R_3 - 1/R_g|$? (where I choose $R_g$)"*

Comment: @ Myridium - very sleek!, thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

You have a cubic equation really and you want to minimize the expression
(acd+abd+abc-bcd)/abcd  with given discrete values. In the ideal case (the equation is verified) you have 0 but if not I think you have min/Max as an option.

Comment: I can follow you to $\frac{R_1 R_2 R_3 + R_1 R_2 R_g + R_1 R_3 R_g + R_2 R_3 R_g}{R_1 R_2 R_3 R_g}$. So, do you want to say that the error can be Zero at best, but  there is no chance to get a solid approximation? I'm confused, please elaborate ;)

Comment: I did not want to give a solution but a hint to find it. The calculation being with discrete values, at first sight I see no other way to compute the resulting possible values; however it could be some shortcuts of course, according to the question (it seems to me that the given quotient min over Max could works maybe).